# Interaction between HTML/Javascript coder and server scripting language coder?

Tags: uml, diagram

I don't want my PHP coder to write Javascript anymore. I want to separate javascript coding and php coding. How should I write documentation about this interaction?

Let's imagine really simple ajax request. As for me documentation should contain sequence flow diagram.

1. user is clicking "edit" button
2. preloader is shown to user
3. ajax request is sent to url /ajax_request/category/{category_id}/; we are expecting answer in json format
4. timer has started; if answer is not recieved within 10 seconds - show alert "Connection timeout, please try to refresh page and try one more time."
5. ajax request is recieved into var data
6. hide preloader
7. check if data.success is false then show alert "Something goes wrong."
8. put data.html in container

As you see, it is really difficult to explain this flow in text format. I know there is UML for describing such things, but I have no experience. All UML samples are too simple and I can't understand how to build more complicated diagrams.

Please, anyone (UML expert), could you show me how UML diagram will look for my example.

I really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Another question - how should I document format of data passing between server side and client site?

Thank you one more time

Comment: Yeah, I know, but as I said all UML samples are too simple and I can't figure out how to build diagram for my sample. :(

Comment: I have found, in my experience, that javascript and server side will exchange data in an intermediary format, such as xml, or JSON.  When I work with members on my team in such a fashion, I just specify what data I want, and the format I expect it in, and let them go to town, then I code my javascript knowing that i can expect data in the specified format... works out well, as that should be the only point of contact...

Comment: To extend my last comment, keep the communication simple... if you over complicate it, there will be more mis-understandings than is needed... just say "I expect this data, and you can expect this data from my interface".  That should set you up for some easy automated testing before you see how your stuff works together.

Comment: Here is the activity diagram 
http://img2.pict.com/87/68/c0/2821163/0/screenshot2b105.png

how do you think, is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

There are more diagrams for your problem. The question is :"What do you want to represent?"

- **Flow from your step 1. to your step 8**
  You shuold draw a Behavior diagrams.
  You can use an Use Case (diagram for represent the actions of user), Activity diagram (represent the life of a algorithm or process) or a State Diagram (if you want to represent the evolution of a specific component in the flow, f.e. the http request).
  Otherside, you can use an Interaction diagram for represent the interdipendence between server and client.
- **Structure**
  Generally you should use a Class diagram. In simple way:

  - a class for client;
  - a class for server;
  - a class for the request;
  - bla bla

This kind of diagram is useless for the usability/functional activity for the user.

- **UML4WEB** You can use the Diagrams of [Conallen](http://www.conallen.org), who made an extension of UML for the WEB [project](http://books.google.it/books?id=B1n8zzPcMbYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=conallen&source=bl&ots=yS0RSg_DR1&sig=lR9qHPxbrCb_r9hJMO4RqM68Tgs&hl=it&ei=G1F1S7TWLc6A_QayvvmuCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false).

Comment: Right now I will try to make some diagrams and will put em here.
It will take some time, so question is still opened./

Comment: http://img2.pict.com/66/20/96/2820920/0/screenshot2b103.png
here is sequence diagram; as I figured out it is not suitable for such situation because we can't add any logic into this diagram

Now I will try Activity diagram

Comment: http://img2.pict.com/22/bf/07/2821050/0/screenshot2b104.png here is activity diagram; it is much better. The only thing I can't figure out how to display in activity diagram is "checking for timeout".